# How to write logs in JSON format?

Tags: syslog-ng

I want to centralize logging on my servers using `syslog-ng` which will write a JSON-formatted line to a file, which in turn will be picked up by `logstash`, which will forward it to `elasticsearch`. This setup works, except for some specific JSON issues.

I format in `syslog-ng` the log to be in JSON via a `destination` stanza:

```
destination d_json { file("/var/log/all_syslog_in_json.log" perm(0666) template("{\"@timestamp\": \"$ISODATE\", \"facility\": \"$FACILITY\", \"priority\": \"$PRIORITY\", \"level\": \"$LEVEL\", \"tag\": \"$TAG\", \"host\": \"$HOST\", \"program\": \"$PROGRAM\", \"message\": \"$MSG\"}\n")); };
```

This usually works fine, but sometimes the JSON ends up malformed due for instance to existing quotes in `$MSG`.

Is there a better way to format the message? I was looking at the [built-in `json-parser`](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/json-parser.html) but it looks like it requires key-value pairs as the input, while I would like to explode the available fields into a JSON entry

**EDIT & SOLUTION:**

I found on [Dustin Oprea' blog](http://the.randomengineer.com/2014/09/16/convert-syslog-events-to-a-json-stream/) the exact solution:

```
destination d_json { file("/tmp/test.json" template("$(format-json --scope selected_macros --scope nv_pairs)\n")); };
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since you want to format the message as JSON, not parse it, you need the format-json() function of syslog-ng (see [Administrator Guide](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/list/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/) > template and rewrite > Customize message format > template functions > format-json).

Recent versions of syslog-ng can send messages directly to Elasticsearch (see [Administrator Guide](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/list/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/) > Destinations > Elasticsearch).

HTH,
Robert

Comment: Following your answer, I read again the docs and while they are really, really obscure I manage to get what I needed. I updated my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, which part of the docs did you find obscure? I'd be happy to improve them.

Comment: Hello Robert: when searching on how to format JSON output, I found `format-json` and `json-parser`. I was not clear on how to use either of them. The macros part does not either explicitly state which elements from the input syslog data get parsed into what fields. I was too harsh, sorry, with the "really, really obscure" statement - it is rather that for someone who is not an expert in the field it is not obvious what to use. I believe that adding a practical example and possibly explain more down-to-earth elements like `selected-macros` or `nv-pairs`would help.

Comment: (cont'd) I also thought that a JSON **input** was required for `format-json` to be used - you mention in the example that * the source is a JSON encoded log message* - which misled me to think that it works with JSON as a source only (which is not true, after very carefully reading the docs). And nevertheless THANK YOU for this great piece of software.

Comment: Hi WoJ, thanks a lot for your feedback and the detailed description of your problem. You were not harsh at all :) I added this to my todo list, and hope to review and improve these parts of the guide in the next weeks. If you encounter any similar problems, let me know, I really appreciate comments.

Comment: Beware of the "directly send to Elasticsearch" part: it may be incompatible with the specific version you're using and may emit cryptic errors and crash.

Comment: Both links are dead.